# Мерцает шрифт на всем сайте при карусели Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть сайт https://tcc.net.ua, на нем Bootstrap 4 и из-за карусели(слайд-шоу) мерцает шрифт, то четкий то нет, на всех пунктах сайтах заметно это.

Пример мерцания https://gyazo.com/9072416d5b9604132447feaf91fc9165

Как такое пофиксить можно ?

Comment: можете по-гуглить кажеться называеться FOUT (Flash Of Unstyled Text),   вот одна из ссылок - https://binarapps.com/blog/fout-with-web-font-loader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#question #accordion .card .card-header h5 a {
   ...
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-16deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-16deg);
    transform: skewX(-16deg);
   ..
}
```

Замените на

```
#question #accordion .card .card-header h5 a {
       ...
        -webkit-transform: skewX(-16deg) translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: skewX(-16deg);
        transform: skewX(-16deg) translateZ(0);
       ..
    }
```

Это пофиксит

> https://gyazo.com/9072416d5b9604132447feaf91fc9165.

Чтобы не дергался другой текст добавите `translateZ(0)` в те стили, где используется `transform`.

Comment: Просто супер, такое простое решение. Я искал везде его!!